# C# .NET adding items dynamically to 2-D arrays?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

What is the most efficient to add items to a multi-dimensional array where you don't know the item count at the start?

Comment: Use a `List<List<T>>`.  Arrays are designed to start with a fixed size; lists are designed to be able to grow.  Otherwise you have to resize the array manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.GetLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get lenght of each dimension, then you can just populate your array using a simple for loop.

For example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x++)
{
     for(int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); y++)
     {
          array[x,y] = "bla,bla...";
     }
}
```